# M1 Panic: acc_cifl2c_cmd_ncwr

Tags: macbook-pro, network, kernel-panic, apple-silicon

M1 MacBook Pro 13" 16GB constantly reboots with the same panic error: **acc_cifl2c_cmd_ncwr**

I've spent some time figuring out who is causing this problem.
It happens only if M1 MacBook Pro connects to wired ethernet only (via thunderbolt obviously) with disabled Wi-Fi.

So:

- Wi-Fi only = no issues
- Wired ethernet with disabled Wi-Fi = Panic: acc_cifl2c_cmd_ncwr

Tried:

- Multiple/different thunderbolt hubs = panic
- Multiple/different thunderbolt cables = panic
- The latest macOS installed from the scratch = panic
- Safe Mode = panic

I tried to contact AppleCare support but they wasted my 4 hours with no results.

The issue has been present since day one we got the M1 processor...

The only solution is to use Wi-Fi only which is a shame for PRO users.

**CRASHLOG:**

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xfffffe00308887c8): "LLC Bus error from cpu1: FAR=0x740192d200 LLC_ERR_STS/ADR/INF=0x11000ffc00000080/0x2280080600c02060/0x5 addr=0x600c02060 cmd=0x14(acc_cifl2c_cmd_ncwr)"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20F71
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: FB10CC0AB8BAC020BC47A50D64476F11
Kernel UUID: 07259C53-9EF7-32FF-821D-8F28A5985DFA
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.120.36
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000027cc8000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe002eccc000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000028810000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe002f814000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002f8e0000
mach_absolute_time: 0x621e4df97f4
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x60d0e4f6 0x0002e5a8
  Sleep   : 0x60d52e97 0x000872f0
  Wake    : 0x60d52e97 0x0009b77a
  Calendar: 0x60d52ec9 0x0003ebb1

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f4
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f4
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f4
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f8
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa51240
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f8
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002fa526f8
Panicked task 0xfffffe1666b44688: 616209 pages, 570 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe166cec9fe0, backtrace: 0xfffffe40202ab090, tid: 2753969
          lr: 0xfffffe002f92ebe4  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab100
          lr: 0xfffffe002f92e9c8  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab170
          lr: 0xfffffe002fa57a70  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab190
          lr: 0xfffffe002fa492b8  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab240
          lr: 0xfffffe002f8e77e8  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab250
          lr: 0xfffffe002f92e658  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab5e0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f92e658  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab650
          lr: 0xfffffe00300e03e8  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab670
          lr: 0xfffffe00308887c8  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab730
          lr: 0xfffffe0030888888  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab7d0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030888330  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab8a0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030888264  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab8b0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030249470  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab8d0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fa4c098  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab910
          lr: 0xfffffe002f8e7950  fp: 0xfffffe40202ab920
          lr: 0xfffffe0031ce1b34  fp: 0xfffffe40202abcc0
          lr: 0xfffffe0031cec2b4  fp: 0xfffffe40202abd00
          lr: 0xfffffe0031ca7c50  fp: 0xfffffe40202abd30
          lr: 0xfffffe003000a2a0  fp: 0xfffffe40202abda0
          lr: 0xfffffe0031ca7cec  fp: 0xfffffe40202abdf0
          lr: 0xfffffe0031caec5c  fp: 0xfffffe40202abe20
          lr: 0xfffffe002ff267c4  fp: 0xfffffe40202abf00
          lr: 0xfffffe002f8f0c38  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe003023c000->0xfffffe003028bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[A0C25545-295B-3538-AA20-D7ED2DFACC78]@0xfffffe0031d50000->0xfffffe0031d53fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily(1.0.0)[15B94521-A6E6-3D71-A842-BBDF5DFCF49B]@0xfffffe0031df8000->0xfffffe0031dfbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[8A98ACCC-D34C-36E3-93F6-D8A2F39C2A51]@0xfffffe0031dfc000->0xfffffe0031e1bfff
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[375417A5-E54E-3435-962C-A5A8B63A70A1]@0xfffffe0031c98000->0xfffffe0031cbbfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler(1.0)[5AD02522-CA32-38AF-B8DF-42A103488990]@0xfffffe0030888000->0xfffffe003088bfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe003023c000->0xfffffe003028bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[A0C25545-295B-3538-AA20-D7ED2DFACC78]@0xfffffe0031d50000->0xfffffe0031d53fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion(1.0.64)[C368FFA0-F8A8-31C8-85F4-FD14104735CB]@0xfffffe0031cdc000->0xfffffe0031d03fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe003023c000->0xfffffe003028bfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE(1)[71FF1161-40A1-3590-82FA-EC25E4BBA66B]@0xfffffe0030798000->0xfffffe00307abfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[F542F73D-2FC5-3BF3-A3D9-EE8865072FAA]@0xfffffe0031d30000->0xfffffe0031d33fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[375417A5-E54E-3435-962C-A5A8B63A70A1]@0xfffffe0031c98000->0xfffffe0031cbbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B0CD5169-B0A8-3682-BB05-ADBC1D65D831]@0xfffffe0031d34000->0xfffffe0031d4ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily(985.2)[AF463BB6-BFD9-376F-8E25-C9915B70E88F]@0xfffffe0031f64000->0xfffffe0031f83fff

last started kext at 5983132342186: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xfffffe002f7c8000, size 16384)
last stopped kext at 5991444649954: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xfffffe002f7c8000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.6
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4050.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  436.121.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelI210Ethernet 2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.120.9
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.28.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   381
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.3
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   224
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4050.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   985.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion    1.0.64
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  405.39
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.6.1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.28.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.28.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    3.55.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   16.15.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR    140.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    985.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.1
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.120.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.121.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.8.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 860592 (Uncompressed 2317552) **
```

Comment: It would help if you included the crash report.  We're not looking over your shoulder when this happens so more info is needed.  You can [edit] your question to include the text of the crash.

Comment: @fsb added the crash report

Comment: "LLC Bus error from cpu1" looks like it could be a driver issue.  Are you running a RAID or an external drive?

Comment: yes, QNAP NAS → switch → ethernet to thunderbolt dongle → MacBook Pro

Comment: Most of the sites I'm seeing with people getting the same error as you have the external storage commonality.  If you disconnect this do you still get the crashing?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the actual kernel panic, but the one keyword you did include indicates that the problem was due to some kind of misconfiguration or unexpected error to do with a write to the last-level cache on the CPU.

Basically this sounds like a concurrency or parallelism error, where two parts of the system are stepping on each other's toes.

I would assume that this can be fixed by a driver update from Apple, if you're using an Apple Ethernet to Thunderbolt dongle. I would report it in as a bug to Apple, or the actual maker of the Ethernet to Thunderbolt dongle if you're using a third party driver.

Comment: I've added the crash report. All thunderbolt hubs work PnP so there is no need to install any 3rd party drivers at all even for Apple Ethernet to Thunderbolt dongle.

Comment: @uiuxgo.com I think you misunderstood me. You did not specify which dongle you were using - therefore I wrote that IF you were using a dongle that does require a driver, then contact that vendor. If you're using the Apple Ethernet dongle, then a driver installation a not required, and you should contact Apple with a bug report.

Comment: Yeah I did that first cuz I have AppleCare but they wasted my 4 hours with no results... that's the problem...

Comment: You have contacted support - that's not what I meant. I meant to file a bug report here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/